# how to export the keras model with resnet101 to tensorflow serving with exporter.export_saved_model method

Tags: keras, tensorflow-serving, resnet

I'm using Keras and resnet 101 for my training and wants to export my model into TensorFlow serving with this method exporter.export_inference_graph and it gives me the error.

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2_block2_1_bn/moving_variance/local_step_1

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you want to Save the Model using `export_saved_model`?

If your Goal is to Save the pretrained model, `resnet` and perform inference using Tensorflow Serving, you can do it using the code mentioned below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
my_resnet = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))


# Add Global Average Pooling Layer
x = my_resnet.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Add a Output Layer
my_resnet_output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

# Combine whole Neural Network
my_resnet_model = Model(inputs=my_resnet.input, outputs=my_resnet_output)

my_resnet_model.save('my_flowers')
```

The last line of code saves the model in `.pb format`.

Now, we need to write the Code for Client File and can perform the inference using Tensorflow Serving.

```
import grpc
import requests
import tensorflow as tf

import cv2
import os
import numpy as np


def main():

  img_array = cv2.imread('daisy.jpg')
  new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  new_array = new_array / 255

  import json
  data = json.dumps(
    {"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": new_array.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3).tolist()})
  print('Data: {} ... {}'.format(data[:50], data[len(data) - 52:]))

  headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
  json_response = requests.post('http://35.226.32.128/v1/models/test0221/versions/1:predict', data=data, headers=headers)
  predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']
  np.argmax(predictions[0])
  dicti
  for flower, label in dicti.items():
    if label == np.argmax(predictions[0]):
      print(flower)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```